# g++ error libboost on centos 7

Tags: boost, installation, g++, centos7

I am trying to install the program my_mead_2.3.4 on my CentOS system.
I run

```
./configure --prefix=`pwd` --boostdir=/usr
```

and then make where I get these errors:

```
g++: error: /usr/lib64/lib/libboost_regex.a: No such file or directory
g++: error: /usr/lib64/lib/libboost_filesystem.a: No such file or directory
g++: error: /usr/lib64/lib/libboost_system.a: No such file or directory
g++: error: /usr/lib64/lib/libboost_serialization.a: No such file or directory
```

I ran yum install boost-devel, but still these files are missing.

I am new to Linux and CentOS, could you please tell me what to do here? Let me know if I should provide any additional Info.

Edit: apparently the program appends /lib to my boostdir. I don't know if this comes from the configure or the make step.

Comment: Script is trying to fetch lib file from `/usr/lib64`. Are you sure you have 64-bit version of the package? Perhaps your have `i386` version of boost installed.

Comment: thanks for your comment. this is what yum tells me: Package boost-devel-1.53.0-27.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Comment: So where does the package install its .a files?

Comment: they are in the /usr/lib64 directory not /usr/lib64/lib. How do I tell the program to look there?

Comment: Looks like your configure script has a bug. Perhaps try to remove `--boostdir=/usr` argument and see if it helps. If not, complain to the authors of the configure script.

Comment: Apparently the program attaches /lib to whatever boostdir you give it. I went through the configure script but I cannot find the cause of the problem.

Comment: Could this also be a problem with 'make'?